# SSIS package loop running with in the same package on the same database

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

Hello Everyone i am using sqlserverdatatools 2014 to develop my ssis package here i stuck in scenario 
i have a package it has 4 data flows it should run in below loop 
1,2,3,4
2, 3, 4
3, 4
4
1, 2, 3, 4
All the data flows are updating same db but due to some Business calculation the package should run above logic please help me how to achieve this 
Thanks in advance 
R
Hari krish

Comment: Your looping logic is unclear. What are those numbers? Are they Data Flow task numbers as in DFT1, DFT2 etc?

Comment: Hello Karthik , yes those are Dataflow tasks DFT1, DFT2 ,DFT3, DFT4

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it should work like that: You could use a Foreach Loop in order to iterate over an array containing your numbers: [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,4,4,1,2,3,4]. You should use the Foreach Item Enummerator for that. Within your Foreach loop you can use Skript tasks infront of your data flows that will execute the data flow dependent on the current variable of your iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.

1. 1.Add a sql expression

   2. Connect to any DB
   3. Change result set to result set
   4. enter the following sql: select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as a (nums)
   5. Save the result to a ADO object
   6. Add a foreach loop
   7. The collection is a ADO.net object
   8. Set it to your ADO object
   9. Add an expression (put 1=1 into just to validate
   10. Add your 4 dataflows
   11. Connect to DF1
   12. Add an expression to to flow @num<2||@num==5
   13. Do the same except altering expression @num<3||@num==5

The end result will be 5 loops processing the following DF in each loop:

1st: 1-4

2nd: 2-4

3rd: 3-4

4th: 4

5th: 1-4

Comment: You need 2 variables nums (object) and num int

Comment: I believe OP needs the DFT's to be executed in that specific order and he is not looking at looping it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you would need to do -

1. Create a table say dbo.DataFlowOrder with column Id int and insert the values ( 1,2,3,4 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
2. Create the following variables - intDataFlowOrderId, objDataFlowOrderIdList,strSQLGetDataFlowOrderIdList
3. Set the value of strSQLGetDataFlowOrderIdList as follows -

   select Id from dbo.DataFlowOrder
4. Drag 'Execute SQL Task'. Set the 'ResultSet' property to 'Full Result Set', 'SQL Source Type' to 'Variable'. Give the appropriate connection and set the 'Source Variable' to strDataFlowOrderIdList. Under the 'Result Set' click on 'Add'. Give the 'Result Name' as 0 and 'Variable Name' as objDataFlowOrderIdList.
5. Drag a 'Foreach Loop' container and connect it to the output of above task. Set the 'Enumerator' as 'Foreach ADO enumerator' and set enumaration variable to 'objDataFlowOrderIdList'. In the 'Variable Mappings' tab, set the Variable to 'intDataFlowOrderId'
6. In the 'Foreach Loop' container, drag 'Execute SQL Task' and rename it say 'SQL - DFT Co-ordinator'. Set the appropriate connection value and put the SQLStatement as 'select 1'.
7. Drag all your 4 DFT's in it. Connect the output of above task i.e. to all the 4 DFT's.
8. In each of the 'Precedence Constraints' connectors, have the 'Evaluation operation' set to 'Expression and Constraint'. 'Precedence Constraints' are nothing but the green line i.e. the output that you are connecting between task to task. For the first DFT, set the 'Expression' as '@[User::intDataFlowOrderId] == 1' (without the quotes). Repeat the same process for the rest of the DFT's with the appropriate number i.e. 2, 3, 4 etc.

Below is a screenshot of how the control flow should look like - 
[image: Control Flow Overview]

Here is a screenshot of the 'Precedence Constraint' -
[image: Precedence Constraint setting]

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me check this once !!